# How to print out numbers in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JS and I coded an "arabic to roman numbers" converter. Everything is working fine when I console log. But the next step is to display these informations in html like following :
Arabic number : 
Roman number :

Here's my code so far :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Converter</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Arabic number :</p>
    <p id="numberInput"></p>

    <p>Roman number :</p>
    <p id="romainInput"></p>

    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the Js part :

```
let romanInput = document.getElementById("romanIput");

let arabicInput = document.getElementById("numberInput");

function convertToRoman(num) {
  const romanToNum = {
    X: 10,
    IX: 9,
    V: 5,
    IV: 4,
    I: 1,
  };

  let roman = "";

  for (let key in romanToNum) {
    while (num >= romanToNum[key]) {
      roman += key;
      num -= romanToNum[key];
    }
  }
  return roman;
}

console.log(convertToRoman(2));
```

I just need to choose a random number in the console between 1 and 10 and to display it. I tried different things with "romanInput.innerHtml = roman.value" and things like that but nothing working so far. Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `roman.value` doesn't make sense, `roman` is just a string.  Did you mean `romanInput.innerHtml = roman;` ?

Comment: yes exactly, sorry I got confused

Answer (score 0):

if you want to generate random number and pass it to your function you can write a function like this:

```
function getRandomNumberBetween(min,max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}
var rndNum = getRandomNumberBetween(1,10);
console.log(convertToRoman(rndNum));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are nearly there. Just add an eventlistener to your input field and actual make it a html input field.

After this you can listen to [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) and read the value which is in the input.

I used the keyup event to update the value immediately.

```js
let romanOutput = document.getElementById("romanOutput");

let arabicInput = document.getElementById("numberInput");

arabicInput.addEventListener("keyup", e =>  convertToRoman(Number(e.target.value)))

function convertToRoman(num) {
  const romanToNum = {
    X: 10,
    IX: 9,
    V: 5,
    IV: 4,
    I: 1,
  };

  let roman = "";

  for (let key in romanToNum) {
    while (num >= romanToNum[key]) {
      roman += key;
      num -= romanToNum[key];
    }
  }
  romanOutput.innerHTML = roman;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Converter</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Arabic number :</p>
    <input id="numberInput" />

    <p>Roman number :</p>
    <p id="romanOutput"></p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had miss spelled [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) as `innerHtml`. That's why it won't work.

```js
let romanInput = document.getElementById("romanIput");

let arabicInput = document.getElementById("numberInput");

function convertToRoman(num) {
  const romanToNum = {
    X: 10,
    IX: 9,
    V: 5,
    IV: 4,
    I: 1,
  };

  let roman = "";

  for (let key in romanToNum) {
    while (num >= romanToNum[key]) {
      roman += key;
      num -= romanToNum[key];
    }
  }
  return roman;
}

arabicInput.innerHTML = convertToRoman(2)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Converter</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Arabic number :</p>
    <p id="numberInput"></p>

    <p>Roman number :</p>
    <p id="romainInput"></p>

  </body>
</html>
```